# Randomized encodings and Indistinguishability obfuscation

Tags: randomness, terminology, encoding, obfuscation

I want to understand the difference between [randomized encodings](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/%7Emp/crypto/mpc2017/slides/day2/yuval-rand.pdf) and [indistinguishability obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indistinguishability_obfuscation) (iO).

Are randomized encodings a special type of iO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, randomized encodings are not really a form of obfuscation. Intuitively, in a randomized encoding, you encode a function $f$ into a simpler function $\hat f$ using randomness:

$\mathsf{Encode}(f;r) \rightarrow \hat f$

such that given $\hat f(x)$, you can reconstruct $f(x)$, and nothing more.

There are two crucial differences with obfuscation: (1) you are not allowed to see $\hat f$ in the clear, but only its evaluation on a point, and (2) this property only gives you security for *a single evaluation of $\hat f$*: if you get $\hat f(x_1), \hat f(x_2)$, this becomes completely broken in general!

On the other hand, obfuscation gives you some $\hat f$ that does not reveal which $f$ was obfuscated (among all functionally equivalent candidates), even if you see its evaluation on many points - actually, even if you get the circuit of $\hat f$ in the clear!

If it helps, randomized encodings are essentially equivalent to garbled circuits, up to some details in the exact template. More precisely, a garbled circuit would be what we call a *decomposable* randomized encoding, where $\hat f(x)$ contains an input-independent part, denoted $\mathsf{G}(f)$ - that's the *garbling* of $f$, and an input-dependent part, denoted $\mathsf{T}_x$.

For example, the standard garbled circuit construction of Yao is a computational randomized encoding of all polysize circuits as a low-depth circuit. In a sense, a garbled circuit gives you a *token-based one-time obfuscation:* given a circuit $f$, you can get a garbled circuit $\mathsf{G}(f)$. Now, given $\mathsf{G}(f)$ and an appropriate *token* $\mathsf{T}_x$ for an input $x$, you can compute $f(x)$ and nothing more.

So, decomposable randomized encodings (*i.e.* garbled circuits) would be a form of obfuscation where:

1. You cannot evaluate the "obfuscated" circuit on an arbitrary input: you need to get a special *evaluation token* for this input
2. You are only allowed to receive a *single* evaluation token

If you relax the second property, you get the notion of *reusable garbled circuit*, which are [known to exist](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/733) under assumptions such as LWE. This comes closer to obfuscation, but is still *very* far from full-fledged obfuscation: you still need an external party with private information that sends you token for every input you want to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that randomised encoding, as you are probably already aware, allows for two functions `f(x)` and `g(x, r)` that satisfy the following two properties.

1. **Correctness:** there exists some function `D` such that `f(x) = D(g(x, r))`.
2. **Privacy:** knowledge of `g(x, r)` will not feasibly reveal any knowledge of `f(x)` to differentiate it from `f(y)` without comparing `g(x, r)` and `g(y, r)`.

On the other hand indistinguishability obfuscation allows a function `f(x)` that satisfies the following two properties.

1. **Completeness:** there exists some function `E` such that `f(x) = E(x)`.
2. **Indistinguishability:** knowledge of `E(x)` will not feasibly reveal any knowledge of `f(x)` to differentiate it from `f(y)` without comparing `E(x)` and `E(y)`.

If `E(x) = g(x, r) = D(g(x, r))` was true, and the properties were otherwise satisfied, then **completeness** and **indistinguishability** would be satisfied as equivalent to **correctness** and **privacy**. Hence, in this case randomised encryption would be equivalent to indistinguishability obfuscation. However, randomised encryption expands further on this to say that `g(x, r)` could be any function, and not necessarily equal to `E(x)`.

Further reading that might be of interest for the topic can be found [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/771.pdf) and [here](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/137817/15m1050963.pdf?sequence=2).

Comment: FYI. We have $\LaTeX$/MathJax to write better.